# How can someone else be able to run my C++ project if I use SFML libraries?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm new to C++ programming and am working on a Pong game. I want to use SFML libraries, but I want to send the project to a friend. Will he be able to run the project without errors if he does not have SFML installed?

Note: I want to send it as a Visual Studio project, not as an executable.

Comment: Create an installer with a program like NSIS and package all of the required dlls and c++ runtime dlls in that installer.

Comment: ***Note: I want to send it as a Visual Studio project, not as an executable.*** Then your friend will have to setup the same environment as you using the same steps you did to setup the environment including installing Visual Studio Community. You may want to create a VM install windows in that VM and then install all the tools and libraries in the VM writing down the steps required to test the required install steps so that your friend will have a relatively easy install experience.

Comment: If your vs project has some dependencies to compile, your friend of course needs these to compile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not always, same compiler yes but for libraries is a little different. That is why I am asking. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @drescherjm That could work actually, I am going to do what the person in the answer suggested. Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make a "libraries" folder to your project file and add there the SFML folder.

After doing that open the SFML folder and go to the bin folder and copy all the .dll files you see.

Then paste the dll files to the folder your vs files are (.vcxproj etc)

Comment: Huge thanks! I am going to do that. Thank you for the reply!